# How to calculate PDF of a function given the PDFs of the input of the function?

Tags: probability, distributions

Example: if $x$ and $y$ have uniform distributions over $[0, b]$ and $[0, 2\pi]$ then find the PDF of the function $x + a*cos(y)$

I have no formal background in statistics and I know little outside of that taught in high school. Which topics do I need to learn in order to answer this question? What is answering such a question called? Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: This is a probability question rather than a statistics question and you can find the answer in an elementary textbook on probability (or in the probability section of a statistics book like Casella and Berger, 1990).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, familiarise yourself with the notion of PDF (probability density function) and continuous random variables. Once you have this theoretical foundation, there are multiples ways to solve this question. Two of them are:

1. Find the PDF of $Z=a\cos(Y)$, which is also uniform in $[-a,a]$. This can be guessed straightforward, but a principled way is to apply [Functions of RVs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#/Functions_of_random_variables).
2. We have two independent RVs $X$ and $Z$, and we want to find the PDF of $Y=X+Z$. Since they're independent, this can be done using [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions). In general, this could've been also solved by finding $P(Y\leq y)=P(X+Z\leq y)$ by 2D integration in the joint probability space, and then differentiating it by $y$.